# Probability of a combination of independent events

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

I have four independent exponential random variables $A,B,N_1,N_2$ with rates $\lambda_A,\lambda_B,\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ respectively. For given values of $t_A$ and $t_B$, I'm looking for the probability of either of the following events occurring:

1. $\{A < t_A\} \cap \{A < N_1\} \cap \{A < B\}$
2. $\{A < t_A\} \cap \{A < N_1\} \cap \{B < A\} \cap \{t_B < B\} \cap \{t_B < N_2\}$

Combined, this gives the event:
$$\{A<t_A\} \cap \{A<N_1\} \cap \Big( \{A < B\} \cup \left( \{B<A\} \cap
 \{t_B<B\} \cap \{t_B<N_2\}\right)\Big)$$

My strategy is to marginalize over $A$ and then $B$, but I'm getting caught up on the bounds of integration. I can reduce it to the following integral:
$$ \int_0^{t_A} \Pr[a < N_1] \cdot \Big(\Pr[a < B] + \Pr[t_B<N_2]\cdot\int_{t_B}^a \Pr[B=b] db\Big) \cdot \Pr[A=a] da $$

But this only seems to hold when $t_B < t_A$ when I tried to simulate it. Should the upper bound on the integral be something like $\max(t_A,t_B)$?

Answer (score 0):

if $t_B > t_A$ then the expression simplifies alot (the 2nd expression becomes impossible).

$B>t_B>t_A>A, but A>B$

Comment: I am aware, but its the simplification step that I'm concerned with. Ignoring condition 1, the expression is $\int_0^{t_A}\Pr[a<N_1]\Pr[t_B<N_2]\int_{t_B}^a \Pr[B=b]db \cdot \Pr[A=a] da$. My concern is the upper bound on the integral is incorrect and should be something like $\int_{t_B}^{\max(a,t_B)}$ then when $t_B > t_A$ the simplifies to 0 and that portion of the expression vanishes.

Comment: yup, that seems like it would work!